# How to make use of auth_group table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have written a class in views.py file for adding a group in auth_group table.
But i am getting an error message saying: -

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_group_name_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (name)=() already exists.

Following is my views.py file code.

```
class AddGroup(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        log.debug("Getting into the function !!")
        try:

            log.debug(request.data)
            group11 = Group.objects.create()
            log.debug(group11)
            group11.save(2, str(request.data['customer']))
            # group11.save(str(request.data['customer']))
            log.debug(group11)
            return Response(request.data['customer']+' created successfully !!', status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Following is my models.py code

```
class MyGroup(GroupManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create(self, group_name):
        # GroupManager.create(group_name)
        group = self.model(
            group_name=group_name,
        )
        group.save(using=self._db)
        return group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass `name` argument to the `create()` method in `AddGroup` class:

```
group11 = Group.objects.create(name="some_name") # here
```

So every new group created with empy name which violates unique constraint.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: I am trying to write a class in models.py so that i can enter values into the auth_group table.

Comment: @VikramSharma check update. You also need to provide name to the `create` method in the view.